# SSHD does not show in PATH, but SSH does?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I am currently working on ssh protocol in python and I have wasted a huge amount of time just to start openssh server. After that I was able to start it and run my python scripts normally. There was no permission issue for either.

But the issue is, when I do `which ssh` it gives the location of openssh client (usr/bin/ssh). But when I try `which sshd` it returns nothing, but the server is working fine till now.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: This seems normal. `sudo which sshd` should print something. Nothing to fix.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski a"which sshd" works fine for me as a regular user on my Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 6 box.  A partial workaround (as root) might be to use find / -type f -executable -name "sshd"

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are right. It is nothing to worry about. But as mentioned by davidgo it should also work without root privilages

Comment: No, because the SSHD daemon needs to be root to start since it opens one of the "low" ports... Also, it is typically used as a service, to its exact location is relevant only in the service definition.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for your help. Its much clear me.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` is usually meant to be run by anybody, `sshd` is not meant to be invoked by regular users; therefore the  former is (e.g.) in `/usr/bin` and the latter in `/usr/sbin`.

Well, these paths may vary. The point is the directory of `ssh` executable is in regular user's `PATH`, but the directory of `sshd` executable is usually not (it should be in `root`'s `PATH` though).

You can change your (regular user's) `PATH` by yourself, but adding `/usr/sbin` to it won't do much good, because either you won't be able to execute files from therein, or you will be formally able to execute them but you will experience permission issues later.

Nothing particularly wrong with this, you shouldn't be able to break the system this way. However this will litter your command line copletion (tab expansion) with executables you will never need to run as a regular user.

These executables need `root` for reasons. For `sshd` the reasons are:

- it is designed to be a system-wide service, a daemon; to start once the system starts, when no users are even logged in; to let other users into the system;
- it often opens a "low" port, regular users are rarely permitted to do so.

`which sshd` returns nothing for you, `sudo which sshd` should return something. This seems normal. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: Except that she CAN be run by regular users - it's not uncommon to do and just launch it on port 2222

Comment: @davidgo:  ‘‘***she*** can be run by regular users’’?  I hope that’s an autocorrect. … But seriously — while it’s true that a regular user can bind a socket to port #2222, what good does it do to run an sshd server unprivileged?  It can’t setuid to any user other than you, and it can’t even verify your password.  I suppose it can support passwordless login as yourself, but what’s the use case?

Comment: Tell me if I got this right. SSHD is a daemon , i.e a system-wide (a server) service so it makes much sense that it lies in the  `root` `PATH` whereas ssh is user service (a client for SSH server) so it is accessed by anyone.

Comment: @adityarawat Basically yes. There are more tools like this. Daemons or not, it doesn't really matter; what matters is they are useful particularly for `root`, not for regular users.